# Trying to set current date and date parameters to past date

Tags: ios, date, parse-platform

I am trying to create a function that pulls data that only has a time stamp of a specific date. It is for a project and the most recent data in the set is from February. I still want to use the standard yesterday, last week, last month parameters.

Is there any way to set the "current date" to a specific date so I can make the time frames based on that instead of the actual current date?

This is what I've tried

```
 NSString *datestr = @"2014-02-16T04:59:50.021Z";
NSDateFormatter *dformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"];

NSDate *date = [dformat dateFromString:datestr];

NSTimeInterval secondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60;

NSDate *yesterday = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval: date -secondsPerDay];
NSDate *lastWeek = [[NSDate alloc]initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: - secondsPerDay * 7];
NSDate *lastMonth = [[NSDate alloc]initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-secondsPerDay * 30];
```

Trying to subtract `secondsPerDay` from `date` yields an arithmetic error. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't subtract an `NSTimeInterval` (which is a `double`) from an `NSDate` (which is an object). You want to send the `dateByAddingTimeInterval:` message to the date from which the time will be subtracted:

```
NSString *datestr = @"2014-02-16T04:59:50.021Z";
NSDateFormatter *dformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"];

NSDate *date = [dformat dateFromString:datestr];

NSTimeInterval secondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60;

NSDate *yesterday = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:-secondsPerDay];
NSDate *lastWeek = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:-(secondsPerDay * 7)];
NSDate *lastMonth = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:-(secondsPerDay * 30)];
```

Note, however, that `lastMonth` will not be exactly correct, since not every month has 30 days. Instead, you may also want to look at `NSDateComponents`:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *todayComponents = [NSDateComponents new];
todayComponents.year = 2014;
todayComponents.month = 2;
todayComponents.day = 16;
todayComponents.hour = 4;
todayComponents.minute = 59;
todayComponents.second = 50;

NSDate *today = [calendar dateFromComponents:todayComponents];

NSDateComponents *offset = [NSDateComponents new];
offset.day = -1;
NSDate *yesterday = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:offset toDate:today options:0];

offset = [NSDateComponents new];
offset.day = -7;
NSDate *lastWeek = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:offset toDate:today options:0];

offset = [NSDateComponents new];
offset.month = -1;
NSDate *lastMonth = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:offset toDate:today options:0];
```